# How to read MySql Column using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have trouble when Reading one column with multible rows from a MySql table.

My code follows below:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> ReadFromColumn(string table, string column)
    {

        query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT {0} FROM {1};", column, table);

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            outColumn = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                outColumn.Add(reader[i].ToString());
            //Read the data and store them in the list

        }

        CloseConnection();
```

For some stupid reason that I can not understand I only get one record from the reader.read. Sending the same Query in MySql renders me a full list of 10 instances?

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to call `reader.Read()` in some type of loop to advance the MySqlDataReader to the next record.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the results:

```
           MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   outColumn.Add(reader[i].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes you are so correct. Sometimes when you are tired you just do not see the obvious, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through the result set as:

```
While (reader.Read()) 
{  
    //Then you can read the values as
   //reader[0].ToString();

}
```